# I used js to create my command syntax, now how can I use it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with .gs script that is successfully generating dynamicnewRichTextValue() parameters which are meant to be injected into a Sheet cell that will contain multiple lines of text each with their own URL. I do not know all of the parameters in advance (might be one text and one link, or two each, or more) which is why I am dynamically generating the parameters.

Let's say the end-state should be this (in this case there are only two line items, but there could be more or less:

```
var RichTextValue=SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText("mailto:fred@abcdef.com,mailto:jim@abcdef.com")
  .setLinkUrl(0,6,"mailto:fred@abcdef.com")
  .setLinkUrl(7,19,"mailto:jim@abcdef.com")
  .build();
```

In my script I don't know how many "setText" parameters or "setLinkUrl" statements I will need to generate, so I am doing it dynamically.

This is simple to handle for "setText" because I can just pass a single variable constructed during an earlier loop that builds the "setText" parameters. Let's call that variable setTextContent, and it works like this:

```
var RichTextValue=SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText(setTextContent)
```

So up to this point, everything is great. The problem is that I have another variable that generates the URL portion of the newrichtextvalue() parameters up to the ".build();" statement. So let's call that variable setUrlContent and it is built in an earlier loop and contains the string for the rest of the statement:

```
.setLinkURL(0,22,"mailto:fred@abcdef.com").setLinkURL(23,44,"mailto:jim@abcdef.com")
```

I am stumped trying to figure out how to attach it to the earlier bit. I feel like this is something simple I am forgetting. But I can't find it after much research. How do I hook up setUrlContent to the code above so that the command executes? I want to attach the bits above and get back to assigning it all to a variable I can put into a cell:

```
var emailCell=SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText("mailto:fred@abcdef.com,mailto:jim@abcdef.com")  // I can dynamically create up to here
  .setLinkUrl(0,6,"mailto:fred@abcdef.com")                 // ...but these last couple lines are 
  .setLinkUrl(7,19,"mailto:jim@abcdef.com")                 // stuck in a string variable. 
  .build();

sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).setRichTextValue(emailCell)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to use your script by dynamically changing the number of emails.

#### Modification points:

- When your following script is run, I think that the links are reflected to `mailto` and `fred@abcdef.`.

  ```
    var emailCell=SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText("mailto:fred@abcdef.com,mailto:jim@abcdef.com")
      .setLinkUrl(0,6,"mailto:fred@abcdef.com")
      .setLinkUrl(7,19,"mailto:jim@abcdef.com")
      .build();

    sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).setRichTextValue(emailCell)
  ```
- I thought that you might have wanted the linked email addresses like below.

  - `fred@abcdef.com` has the link of `mailto:fred@abcdef.com`.
  - `jim@abcdef.com` has the link of `mailto:jim@abcdef.com`.

In this answer, I would like to propose the modified script for above direction.

#### Modified script:

```
var inputText = "mailto:fred@abcdef.com,mailto:jim@abcdef.com";  // This is your sample text value.

var ar = inputText.split(",").map(e => {
  var v = e.trim();
  return [v.split(":")[1], v];
});
var text = ar.map(([e]) => e).join(",");
var emailCell = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(text);
var start = 0;
ar.forEach(([t, u], i) => {
  var len = t.length;
  emailCell.setLinkUrl(start, start + len, u);
  start += len + 1;
});
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,1,1).setRichTextValue(emailCell.build());
```

- In this modification, `inputText` is splitted to the hyperlink and the text (for example, when your sample value is used, it's `fred@abcdef.com` and `mailto:fred@abcdef.com`.), and the text including the hyperlink are put to the cell.
- In this case, for example, even when `var inputText = "mailto:fred@abcdef.com,mailto:jim@abcdef.com"` is modified to `var inputText = "mailto:fred@abcdef.com"` and `var inputText = "mailto:fred@abcdef.com,mailto:jim@abcdef.com,mailto:sample@abcdef.com"`, each hyperlink are reflected to each text.

#### Note:

- When you want to the hyperlink of `mailto:fred@abcdef.com` to the text of `mailto:fred@abcdef.com`, you can also use the following modified script.

  ```
    var inputText = "mailto:fred@abcdef.com,mailto:jim@abcdef.com";  // This is your sample text value.

    var ar = inputText.split(",").map(e => e.trim());
    var emailCell = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(inputText);
    var start = 0;
    ar.forEach((t, i) => {
      var len = t.length;
      emailCell.setLinkUrl(start, start + len, t);
      start += len + 1;
    });
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,1,1).setRichTextValue(emailCell.build());
  ```

#### References:

- [newRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newrichtextvalue)
- [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)
- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)